# How to read float data from a file in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have a file with float numbers and I want to read it and save the values in an array to do some math operations. Then I need to print the new array in another file. All the ways that I found reads the file as a string and I also don't know how to convert string to a float array.

Comment: The [`float` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353752.aspx) converts from `string`.

Comment: `float` will throw an Exception if the string is not parsed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we could assume that each float in the file on its own line then you could do something like this:

```
open System
open System.IO    

let readFloats filePath = 
    let strs = File.ReadLines(filePath) // Read file line by line
    strs |> Seq.map (fun str -> System.Double.TryParse(str)) // TryParse returns pair (Boolean * float value). Boolean is true if string parsed correctly 
         |> Seq.filter (fun (success, _) -> success) // filters out wrong  (not parsed strings)
         |> Seq.map snd // transforms sequence of pairs (bool * float) into float only
```

Comment: If you want to be really cute (and have no error handling) you can boil it down to simply `let readFloats = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines >> (Array.map float)`

Comment: For that matter, @Petr could have written `let readFloats = System.IO.File.ReadLines >> Seq.map System.Double.TryParse >> Seq.filter fst >> Seq.map snd`

Comment: Thanks everybode for the help, but it's not changing correctly the string to float. The sequence is like this `seq[-1.998750; -0.048750; 0.884451; 2.482136; ...]` and the output is like this         `seq [-1998750.0; -48750.0; 884451.0; 2482136.0; ...]`

Comment: Maybe it is local culture specific. TryParse method has an overload taking a couple of extra parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx